# reformatting command output within bash script

Tags: shell-script

within script the attempt here is to remove the : and then revert the / to \
within the print out

currently I have to display the linux path: 
The home directory is located here:
rtp1-filer-ns:/homedir-private/private007/user

and would like to reformat as for my users ease 
Windows path to home directory:
\rtp1-filer-ns\homedir-private\private007\user

currently this part of the script is as follows

```
echo "The shell is: `ypmatch $EndUser passwd | awk -F\: '{ print $7 }'`"
echo ""
echo "The home directory is located here:"
   ypmatch $EndUser auto_home 
echo ""
echo "Windows path to home directory:"
echo "\\\\`ypmatch $EndUser auto_home | awk -F':' '{print $1}'`\\$EndUser"
```

gives me the print out of :

```
The home directory is located here:
rtp1-filer-ns:/homedir-private/private007/user

Windows path to home directory:
\\rtp1-filer-ns\user
```

assuming i can use sed /awk something of the sorts , open for suggestions
$EndUser is a defined var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `bash`

First approach - use parameter substitution

```
#use command substitution to set command output into variable var
var=$(ypmatch $EndUser auto_home)
#strip out the first :
var=${var/:}
#replace all instances of / with \
var=${var//\//\\}
echo $var

rtp1-filer-ns\homedir-private\private007\user
```

Second approach - use arrays

```
# Set path components into array frags
IFS=/ read -a frags < <(ypmatch $EndUser auto_home)

# Strip ":" off rtp1-filer-ns
frags[0]="${frags[0]%:}"

# Set IFS to \ to print frags \-separated
echo "$(IFS=\\ ;printf '%s\n' "${frags[*]}";)"

rtp1-filer-ns\homedir-private\private007\user
```

Comment: Awesome ! works like a charm ! Thanks Much!